Drawbacks of making the default post-type: post hierarchical
I want to know about all the drawbacks and consequences/errors I might face if I make the WordPress's default post-type: post, hierarchical. Is it recommended? I have a requirement where I need to create child posts and it should be post only and can't create any Custom Post Type.
Please let me know what are the odds I am gonna face if i make the default post-type: post hierarchical.

I think it's safe to turn the default post type as hierarchical. The only difference is that it will have the field post_parent filled on DB, so you can correctly link one post to another with functions and accessing $post->post_parent property.
If you ever needs to go back, or if for some reason you deactivate the hierarchy property, you should not lose your post association either.

Thanks. I have written the following code.
function make_posts_hierarchical( $args ) {
$args['labels']['name']                = 'Post';
$args['labels']['singular_name'] = 'Post';
$args['labels']['menu_name']     = 'Post';
$args['hierarchical']                     = true;
$args['support']                            = array_merge($args['supports'], array('page-attributes'));
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_post_type_args', 'make_posts_hierarchical' );
